# Can I use / mention a third party payment provider in my app

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase

After reading several threads on Stackoverflow / Reddit it's still quite confusing what is allowed on Android / iOS regarding payments.

I have a an app available for iOS and Android and a web app dashboard. The iOS / Android / Web app uses a API where your profile and statistics are stored.
To cover the costs of the server I want to add a premium membership feature.
Users can subscribe on a monthly / yearly base. 
This allows the user to get more statistics available in the app (iOS, Android and Webapp).

The idea is the same as Spotify (free account / paid account) with the difference that you get music 
without ads with Spotify and here you will get access to more statistics data / more filter options in the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using subscription method you need to use apple In-App purchase which you are using. 
Regarding mentioning the payment provider, you can write in the description about how your app let users use the in-app purchase feature and list out the plans for more clarifications.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, looks like In App Payment is the way to go.
Noted that a similair app does it through a third party provider using a webview, but didn't get cought by Android and iOS

Comment: I once just mentioned in the app "You can't upgrade from the app, please use your account in the web" and apple rejected my app. They insist to use In-App only since  my app is for streaming.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. Will checkout IAP